# Formula for a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ with no derivative on integers.

Tags: calculus, limits

I was asked to find a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ which has derivative for all numbers except integers.

Then I remembered of the greatest integer function, and built the function below on desmos, which clearly has no derivative for integers.

Is there an explicit formula for this function, similar for that for the greatest integer function ?

Note: I built this graph by using piecewise functions, and only for $-5 \le x \le 5$.
[image]

Comment: You could define it piecewise in general, according the parity of $\lfloor x \rfloor$.  It's constant if that number is even and it has slope $1$ if it is odd.  For an alternative function, not requiring piecewise definition, you could try to adapt something like $|\sin (x)\,|$.

Comment: Such a formula would be rather ugly. How about $(\{x\}-\frac12)^2$ instead? ($\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.)

Comment: here you go - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pc8ttirb0c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation
$$\Bigg\vert\frac x2-\left\lfloor\frac x2\right\rfloor-\frac12\Bigg\vert+\frac x2+\frac12$$
works. However, for your assignment, I would recommend writing something like
$$\begin{cases}n+1,&x\in\phantom{{}+1}[2n,2n+1],~n\in\Bbb Z\\
x-n,&x\in[2n+1,2n+2],~n\in\Bbb Z\end{cases}$$
since it's clearer.

Comment: Desmos link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wg2rsxdsa8